# Search database UWP

Tags: c#, sql, uwp

I have UWP app and need to search for mobile number in my database.

Now I make search like this:

```
 searchButton.Click += delegate

            {

                telephone = searchtext.Text;

                    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database= ******;Data Source=**********;User Id=**********;Password=********; SslMode=None; CharSet=utf8"))
                    {

                        connection.Open();


                        MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE N'%+380675090373%'", connection);
                       EncodingProvider ppp;
                       ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
                        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);
                        MySqlDataReader reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\t{12}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)
                             , reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3),reader.GetString(4), reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6),reader.GetString(7), reader.GetString(8), reader.GetString(9),reader.GetString(10), reader.GetString(11), reader.GetString(12));


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                    }
                    reader.Close();

                    //Debug.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
                }
           };
```

I need to take string from `textbox` and search for string that I take from it.

I made taking string like this `telephone = searchtext.Text;` Where I need to paste `telephone` variable?

I know that is simple question, but I need help.

Thank's

Comment: For security's sake, you shoud remove/anonymise the connection string when you post code samples on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty version : replace the phone number in your SQL statement by your telephone variable.

```
MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE N'%" + telephone + "%'", connection);
```

**This is not safe if you don't check user input !** You are creating an opening for SQL injection...

For a safer version, you should use parameters. Below is an example, inspired from [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) :

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE N'%' + @telephone + '%'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", "+3333333333");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you sql command to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE N'%' + @telephone + '%'";
```

Before executing your sql command, add this line:

```
createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephoneNumber", telephone);
```

Comment: Try to paste, but have errors.

Error CS0841 Cannot use local variable 'createCommand' before it is declared 


Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'SqlParameter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Milano